# How to edit a spreadsheet with Coldfusion

Tags: excel, coldfusion

Theres plenty of docs on this and i've been through them all. However none quite answer my question. I want to edit a spreadsheet with Coldfusion. Im going to stress EDIT here because essentially what I'd like to do is open a spreadsheet that already has a template in it and insert some data. Many of the methods i've seen involve reading in the data from a spreadsheet into some query object, editing it and then writing it back out which inevitably screws up the nice template formatting.

I though this might work, but when i try to write the file i get a NullPointerException. The a variable seems to be picking up the spreadsheet template okay though.

```
<cfscript> 
    a = SpreadSheetRead("#theFileCopy#");
    SpreadsheetAddRow(a,"150,ENGL,95,Poetry 1",8,1); 
    SpreadsheetWrite(a,"#theFileCopy#","yes"); 
</cfscript> 

Stack Trace
at cfRelocationForm2ecfc1823847668$funcPRODUCERELOCATIONFORM.runFunction(xxx/xxx/RelocationForm.cfc:118) 

 at   cfRelocationForm2ecfc1823847668$funcPRODUCERELOCATIONFORM.runFunction(xxx/xxx/RelocationForm.cfc:118) 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString.toCTFont(XSSFRichTextString.java:458)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString.getFontOfFormattingRun(XSSFRichTextString.java:397)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.getColumnWidth(ColumnHelper.java:368)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:337)
    at coldfusion.excel.Excel.autoResize(Excel.java:1336)
    at coldfusion.excel.Excel.autoResize(Excel.java:1327)
    at coldfusion.excel.Excel.writeExcel(Excel.java:4824)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.SpreadSheetWrite(CFPage.java:7924)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.SpreadSheetWrite(CFPage.java:7895)
    at cfRelocationForm2ecfc1823847668$funcPRODUCERELOCATIONFORM.runFunction(xxx\xxx\xxx\RelocationForm.cfc:118)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:518)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:660)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:469)
    at coldfusion.filter.ComponentFilter.invoke(ComponentFilter.java:193)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:442)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:155)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doGet(CFCServlet.java:289)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am now trying to use this method to remove the other sheets from the spreadsheet.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#theFileCopy#" name="spreadSheetVar" >     
    <cfset spreadsheetRemoveSheet(spreadsheetVar,"Sheet1")>
    <cfset spreadsheetRemoveSheet(spreadsheetVar,"Sheet2")>
    <cfset spreadsheetRemoveSheet(spreadsheetVar,"Sheet3")>
    <cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFileCopy#"  name="spreadsheetVar" overwrite="true" >
    <cfoutput>Finished</cfoutput>
```

Removing the sheet3 line makes this work. As soon as I add sheet3 to the remover then i get a nullpointer. Sheet3 definitely exists.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace as well

Comment: Done, ive censored some file paths

Comment: Im pretty much hitting this null pointer exception with every method i try. I couldnt update a sheet because it told me the sheetname already exists (pretty nonsensical for an update statement) but it would let me write another sheet to the file with the template and my data. So now im trying to remove the other sheets in the spreadsheet and im getting the null pointer again.

Comment: try doing a `<cfdump var="#spreadSheetVar#">` to see what actually loaded in

Comment: Its definitely loading in the proper spreadsheet, it just refuses to write out that spreadsheet object to a new file. The only thing it will let me do it write it back to the same file as a new spreadsheet.

Comment: lorless, did you ever get this to work?  I just ran into a need very much like yours...

Comment: Sorry this was a long time ago. I couldn't even write a line of coldfusion these days but if i remember right yes i did eventually get this working